# if-else is not producing the expected output in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a string:

```
> all_scn[1]
[1] "Cars_20160601_01.hdf5"
```

I want to use it to repeat some numbers based on a variable `last_step`:

```
> last_step
[1] 439
```

### if-else statement:

```
> ifelse(substring(all_scn[1], 1, 1)=="C",
         rep(seq(0, last_step-1, 1), 13),
         rep(seq(0, last_step-1, 1), 12))  
[1] 0
```

But you see that instead of repeating a numeric vector of `0:438`, 13 times, it just produces zero. Outside of`ifelse` I get following:

```
> rep(seq(0, last_step-1, 1), 13)
   [1]   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28
  [30]  29  30  31  32 . . .  (I truncated the output due to space limitation)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So the first line of `?ifelse` says: "ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test". Your boolean test is a vector of length one. This is a very common novice mistake to confuse `ifelse` as a sort of shorthand for a typical `if () ... else` clause, but it's not.

Comment: Thanks for this. It would never have crossed my mind that this is the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help("ifelse")`:

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
>   with  elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
>   element of  test is TRUE or FALSE.

This means that if the shape of `test` is a vector with just one element, the output will be a vector with just one element. That is the case with your `test`.

```
substring(all_scn[1], 1, 1) == "C"
#[1] TRUE
```

In cases like this, you don't need to *vectorize* because there is nothing to vectorize. All you need a simple `if/else`.

```
if(substring(all_scn[1], 1, 1) == "C")
    rep(seq(0, last_step-1, 1), 13)
else
    rep(seq(0, last_step-1, 1), 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `ifelse` in a wrong way. It doesnot work like you have guessed. You imagined `ifelse(condition, result_if _true, result_if_false)` just like in `excel`. But it works differently in R.
Take the following example from R documentation:

```
> x <- c(6:-4)
> x
[1]  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4  

> sqrt(ifelse(x >= 0, x, NA))
[1] 2.449490 2.236068 2.000000 1.732051 1.414214 1.000000 0.000000      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
Warning message:
In sqrt(x) : NaNs produced
```

> You can see NaNs (Not a Number) produced, because sqrt() of a negativve number is an imaginary number, hence NaN. It produced an error. Now lets see the same for ifelse.

```
> sqrt(ifelse(x >= 0, x, NA))
[1] 2.449490 2.236068 2.000000 1.732051 1.414214 1.000000 0.000000       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

> See, no errors.
>
> The solution for you to is to use simple if...else condition.

```
if (condition){
statement if true } else {
statement if false }
```